# How to stop autoplay of video using iframe tag on Safari browser

Tags: iframe, embedded-video

i am embedding a video using Quick time in website and it starts to play automatically upon loading page.

Here is the code embed video.

```
<iframe SRC="${signedVideoURL}&autoStart=false" TYPE="image/xmacpaint"PLUGINSPAGE="https://www.apple.com/quicktime/download"QTSRC="${signedvideoURL}&autoStart=false" WIDTH="480" HEIGHT="297" AUTOPLAY="false" CONTROLLER="true" SCALE="ToFit"> </iframe>
```

Browser -  Safari 5.1.1

I have also tried passing parameter autoplay=0, that didnot work either.
Can any one suggest how to stop this autoplay?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of this but try it anyway (if its not the true answer, it shouldn't be far from it): put the argument `autoplay=false` in the `src` String of the `iframe` youtube video tag. Append it as usual with the `&` character.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Add `&autoplay=0` to your url